# Subjunctive Mood/Mode Question

Tags: subjunctive-mood

I am trying to understand subjunctive mood/mode. Would the following sentence be subjunctive? If I ever meet a sycophant, I will walk away.

Comment: No, 'subjunctive' is a clause type distinguished by the use of a plain form verb, e.g. "It is vital [that I **be** kept informed]"; "I insisted [that he **meet** her]". Semantically, subjunctives are characterised by invoking the concept of compliance. In the first example, compliance is said to be vital, and in the second I insisted on compliance.

Comment: 'The subjunctive is a specific verb form. It usually expresses something that you wish for, or a hypothetical rather than actual situation: If only I were ten years younger.'[ODO](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=subjunctive&oq=subjunctive&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.3841j1j8&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8).

Comment: No, Nigel, the subjunctive is a clause type that uses a plain form verb, just as imperatives and infinitivals do. "Were" clauses are not subjunctives, but a special mood form called 'irrealis', an untidy relic from an earlier system. Semantically, subjunctives invoke compliance, as in the two examples I gave.

Comment: That's the CGEL terminology. They use "subjunctive" strictly for what's often called "the present subjunctive", based on the infinitive, which is the present stem in most cases; it's a construction limited to subordinate clauses and governed by specific predicates. The so-called "past subjunctive" is the one that CGEL calls "irrealis". Both are relics of past English inflections, which are still there, and both still subjunctive, in German. **That's** why talking about "subjunctive" is confusing; there are too many ways to use the term, which is marginal at best in English.

Comment: Indeed it is based on CGEL, and I'm fully aware of their approach to the subjunctive. I think we have to adopt a grammar and adhere to it, and since CGEL is currently the best grammar available today, it makes good sense to promote its claims. I endorse H&P's claim that the infinitive is not a verb form (English of course does not have an infinitival form of the verb like, say, French, does) but a clause type based on the plain form of the verb, as are infinitival and imperative clauses. That is an entirely sensible and logical approach.

Comment: Indeed it is entirely sensible and logical. It just isn't standard, that's all.

Comment: @BillJ internet is filled with 'were' clause denoting subjunctive form. I still don't understand the use of it. I understanding on this topic is same as that of Nigel

Answer (score 1):

The subjunctive mood is used to express a thought that is a wish, a suggestion, or non-factual.

There is a lot of information about this on the Internet, so I am not going to give an extensive explanation or provide examples, but if your sentence were to be recast in the subjunctive mood, it would read:

If I were ever to meet a sycophant, I would walk away.

See also
http://www.grammar-monster.com/glossary/subjunctive_mood.htm
http://www.englishteachermelanie.com/advanced-english-grammar-the-subjunctive-mood/

Answer (score 0):

No. It's future conditional. 
Subjunctive: if I ever were to meet a sycophant, I would walk away. 
Props to Bill and Nigel, who must be academic linguists. 
Hoping this answer is helpful too,
Brad